# PostgreSQL Insert Values Into Rows

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to insert values using the below query, but the `WHERE` condition of the query appears to not be working properly as all values are inserted and not just the values that meet the `WHERE` condition:

```
INSERT INTO artist (type)
    SELECT artist_type
    FROM artist, database
    WHERE database.artist_name IN (artist.name);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this `database.artist_name= artist.name`

Comment: @lightsouls I have tried this already and unfortunately it results in the same issue

Comment: `SELECT a.artist_type
    FROM artist a
   join  database d
    WHERE d.artist_name = a.name` ?